# Gateway to another computer for internet access

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, gateway

Computer 1 has 2 network cards: One on the 192.168.1.0/24 network, with internet access. And one on the 10.10.10.0/24 network.

Computer 2 has one network card, on the 10.10.10.0/24 network.

I would have thought that setting a default gateway for computer 2 of 10.10.10.5 (IP address of computer 1) would give Computer 2 access to internet. But it doesn't.

How can I give Computer 2 internet access by routing its traffic to Computer 1?

Or is this simply impossible?

Comment: relates to https://superuser.com/questions/1363997/connect-device-to-internet-using-a-linux-computer and https://superuser.com/questions/467806/linux-route-add-between-static-lan-and-wifi-gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that you need to do, both on Computer 1:

1. First, as sudo, issue:

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
2. Now, again as sudo:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```

   where I assumed the interface on the subnet 192.168.0.0/24 is called eth0, otherwise change accordingly.

Now try again from Computer 2. If this does not work, disable the firewall on computer 1, **except** for the previous rule. This´ll do it.

Comment: thanks!  also, to others reading : be sure to have a valid DNS server (look at /etc/resolv.conf)

Comment: Could you explain why the second step is needed and what it does?