# Connect device to internet using a Linux Computer

Tags: linux, router, gateway

I have the next architecture:

[image: architecture]

[**Device** Eth0]--LAN---[Eth 0 **Linux Computer** Wth0]--Wifi--[Router Wifi]

Device Eth0 :IP:10.0.0.15, MK:255.255.255.0,GW:10.0.0.2

Linux Computer Eth0: IP:10.0.0.2, MK:255.255.255.0,GW: -
Linux Computer Wth0: IP192.168.1.10, MK:255.255.255.0, GW:192.168.1.1

Router Wifi: IP:192.168.1.1/24

And I need that the Device gets internet connection using the Linux Computer like gateway.

The Linux computer gets internet connection using the Router Wifi, this works fine. And the Device is connected to Linux Computer using Ethernet cable. From computer I can do a ping to the Device, and works. But from the Device can not connect to internet.

I tried to use route rules, iptables... but the Device can not connect to internet.

Do you know How can connect the Device to internet using the Linux Computer like gateway?

Comment: You need to enable IP forwarding and NAT on the Linux computer. There are plenty of tutorials for that online. Yes, it involves `iptables` for the NAT. If you found a tutorial and it didn't work, please edit your question with a link to the tutorial, and describe exactly what you did, how you debugged it and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should work with the following commands

at first enable ip forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

reset iptables rules

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
```

allow forwarding from the local network

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wth0 -j ACCEPT
```

allow responses back in

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wth0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

masquerade the ip address

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

afterwards you need to configure the eth0 IP of your Linux computer (10.0.0.2) as a gateway in your device and configure the DNS Server to the IP of your wifi router or some other public dns Service (e.g. 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8)

Comment: I tested your solution and works fine, but If we restart the Linux Computer we lost the configuration.Do you know some way to save permanently this configuration?

Comment: to make this ip_forward setting persistent you need to add the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` to the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.
as far as I know there is no standard way to make the iptables rules persistent. on debian and ubuntu there is a package called `iptables-persistent` which does restore the iptables rules on startup. they can be saved by running `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Comment: In my case it seems that manually editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncommenting the `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` line was the missing piece that made this whole setup work. I'd tried the echo command at the start of this answer but got permission denied, and it seems running it as root was also ineffective.